# Show that $\mathbb P^n$ has a cell decomposition...

Tags: general-topology

I dont know were to start here. I got a solution from my teacher but I dont get it at all, maybe another point of view can make understand the proof better.[image: Problem to solve]

Comment: It might help to know something more about your teacher's solution and what about it you would like to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb{P}^0$ be a point, then $\mathbb{P}^1 \cong S^1$ is a 1-disk (closed interval) with its boundary glued to $\mathbb{P}^0$.

$\mathbb{P}^2$ is just a 2-disk with its boundary glued with some function to $\mathbb{P}^1$ and so on, you just need to come up with the induction and the functions $f: \partial D^{n+1} \cong S^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ to get an isomorphism $\mathbb{P}^{n+1} = \mathbb{P}^n \cup_f D^{n+1}$.